# is there a way to restart ubuntu through shell into specific compiled kernel?

Tags: grub2

Im using **ubuntu 14** os , and I compiled several kernels so I can test and modify them .

When Im physically infront of the computer and I want to load specific kernel version , I press **Esc** while the pc is booting and I get into **Grub** menu and from there I choose the version of kernel I want to load.

But let say I work remotly on the computer through **ssh**  , and I want to restart the pc into a specific kernel version .. I tried to search for **Grub** options but couldnt find something that worked.

Does any one know how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `GRUB_DEFAULT` variable in `/etc/default/grub`. Then run `update-grub2` and `reboot`.

For example use the second entry as default (they are starting at `0`):

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -i 's/^GRUB_DEFAULT=.*/GRUB_DEFAULT=1/' /etc/default/grub
update-grub2
reboot
```

This script needs to run as root.

---

**For users from other Linux distributions**: The commands above may vary on your system. It has been tested only on Ubuntu. (However, the question is tagged as *Ubuntu*)